# Could a race of bird people defend themselves against humans?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, weapons, avian

So there’s a society of evolved birds, roughly the size of humans but still very much birds. They have a similar level of intelligence as ourselves and are able to speak human language similar to a grey parrot. They have wings but are unable to fly due to their size.

Their society has developed in isolation in the South American rainforests other than minor encounters but with greater deforestation they are now in contact with humanity. Should the Bird People come into conflict with humans, which inevitably they will, how could they defend themselves as in what type of weaponry and/or tactics would work for them?

EDIT

The birds were created as the result of a experimentation. They are more proficient than humans in close combat as they have talons and beaks and can do some real damage. They do have access to the laboratory but the equipment there is designed for human physiology so they wouldn't be able to use it.

They wouldn't be fighting an army or government. Its more of a mercenary/poacher type force similar to that of Jurassic Park: Lost World.

Comment: Questions like this are normally closed as too opinion based.

Comment: What abilities do they possess that humans don't? Except maybe more fragile, hollow bones?

Comment: No isolated human tribe could defend against modern world. So what's the time frame here? Or how your birds are superior? Do they have some magic? Industry somehow hidden from us for so long?.. Why couldn't humans just [nuke it from orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGOtZDk6wRc)?

Comment: Grey parrots don't speak human language; they mimic. Do your bird people speak language, or simply mimic? (There's a very large difference between the two.)

Comment: @Mołot there's a guy in Brazil who is the last of his tribe. No one has seen him in over a decade. He essentially "owns"several hundred square miles of rainforest that is protected from poaching and forestry in order to leave him alone. In the event of his death, the land falls to the government. So, not impossible, but definitely difficult.

Comment: Have just added edit to explain a bit more of the strengths. @Azuaron they are able to speak and learn language in the same way we can, as well as human language they can also speak to other species of bird

Comment: @Draco18s He's not defending, he's left alone on our own accord. He's not defending against anything.

Comment: If it is a Jurassic Park scenario then you have basically already seen it, like 4 times. Velociraptors as shown in those films could be replaced by smart large birds almost effortlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barring any unknown, highly advanced technology or characteristics that the Bird People might possess that could aid them, it's likely they'll be destroyed fairly quickly.  Modern human technology is very efficient at killing, particularly in the hands of motivated humans.

Close combat might be their advantage - ambushes and hit-and-run raids - but humans have been more or less trying to get away from close-quarters combat for our entire existence.  We don't naturally possess any real close combat advantages without technology, especially against predators.

Hunters and poachers would be more susceptible to these types of attacks because they have a vested interest in preserving some part of the prey.  They're not really interested in a fair fight though.  I imagine after a few deadly first encounters they'd resort to traps and remote-operated weapons for their purposes.

Their best bet is to gain some sort of international recognition or protected status.  However, being the result of human experimentation, it is about equally as likely they will be viewed as an abomination and exterminated.

Answer (score 0):

What tech level are the humans? Because things like the Terror Bird ([link1](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2405749/Giant-prehistoric-terror-bird-thought-ruthless-predator-actually-VEGETARIAN.html) and [link2](https://www.thoughtco.com/terror-bird-phorusrhacos-1093597)) could EASILY hold their own against primitive humans, especially if they had a social structure and intelligence level at the same level. The problem is that without hands their technological development is gonna be REALLY stunted, if nonexistent, so there will be little they can do against modern weapons. Ambush tactics, using their large beak, kicking with their legs, feathers make for a surprisingly good defense against impact weapons, so pound for pound I bet a smart terror bird would be the warrior equivalent of a human swordsman. But archers, crossbows, and firearms are gonna wreck them though, no getting around it. But archery in humid environments really sucks, as do early firearms, so they may have a decent advantage even then.

Are there diseases they can give us? Or us them? If so that would probably be the deciding weapon of war, much like it was for most of human history.